# CentOS + PHP: Processes limited with shell_exec

Tags: php, apache, centos

I have a `httpd` process running (just `apache2`), with PHP. In `index.php` I have the following code in the file:

```php
echo shell_exec("sudo -u apache python3 /root/folder/script.py 2>&1");
```

Which should execute a a program (which its doing nicely). The program takes ~40 seconds to return something, so it takes a bit. Ive created another python program which is multithreaded. Which makes a request 400 times on the same time to the url, which should start 400 processes.

When I run the command `top -c`, I see that the CPU is only at 9% while that should be higher. I tried the next command, `ps xa | grep apache | wc -l`. That returns 101 processes, I've done the command multiple times and its always at 101.

Before I did the command `ps xa | grep apache | wc -l`, I first made a mistake and tried `ps xa | grep apache2 | wc -l`, I don't run apache2, but that still gave me the numer 1. So my theory is that 101 - 1 = 100. Which is a too beautiful number.

So this should be some type of maximum / limit / cap. Where can I configure this?

Thanks for your time

===== EDIT =====

I think its queue'ing the requests, while when I login into the server and run the python script manually, the script just normally works without any slow downs etc.